# Executable binary file not working after XOR encryption and decyption

Tags: encryption, xor, jscript, wsh

I want to encrypt an exe file (file.exe), write the encrypted version to a text file (fileenc.txt) and decrypt the data in the text file back to another exe file (filedec.exe).

file.exe and filedec.exe are the same and are expected to function the same way.

However, when I try to do this the filedec.exe does not work. Error Popup says: "This app cannot run on your PC".

Please what could be the problem?

However, when I just read the file.exe, write to fileenc.txt without encryption or decryption, and then read fileenc.txt and write data to filedec.exe without encryption or decryption, filedec.exe seems to work fine.

Also, when I try encrypting and decrypting a text file with this code, it works fine too.

But when I encrypt and decrypt an exe on the fly, filedec.exe doesn't work.

Please help me out. Thank you everyone.

Here is my full code:

```
Main();

function Main() {
    var arrKey;

    arrKey = "encryptionkey";
    
    //Encrypt file.exe and write the encrypted form to file.txt
    Crypt( "C:\\...\\file.exe", "C:\\...\\fileenc.txt", arrKey );
    
    //Decrypt the previously encrypted file.txt and write the decrypted form to filedec.exe
    Crypt( "C:\\...\\fileenc.txt", "C:\\...\\filedec.exe", arrKey );
    
    //NOTE: file.exe and filedec.exe are expected to work fine when executed
    
}


function Crypt(fileIn, fileOut, key) {
    var fileInRead;
    
    //Read fileIn
    var adTypeBinaryRead = 1;
    var BinaryStreamRead;
    BinaryStreamRead = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    BinaryStreamRead.Type = adTypeBinaryRead;
    BinaryStreamRead.Open();
    BinaryStreamRead.LoadFromFile(fileIn);
    fileInRead = BinaryStreamRead.Read();
    
    //Convert fileIn binary data to string
    var objRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    var DefinedSize = 1024;
    var adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2;
    var adFldLong = 0x80;
    var adVarChar = 201;
    var adTypeText = 2;
    objRS.Fields.Append("filedata", adVarChar, DefinedSize, adFldLong);
    objRS.Open();
    objRS.AddNew();
    objRS.Fields("filedata").AppendChunk(fileInRead);
    var binString = objRS("filedata").value;
    objRS.close();

    //Make key as long as string version of fileIn
    while (key.length < binString.length) {
        key += key;
    }
    key = key;
    
    //crypt converted string with key
    var k, ss, q;
    var cryptresult = "";
    i = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < binString.length; index++) {
        k = key.substr(i, 1);
        q = binString.substr(i, 1);
        ss = q.charCodeAt(0);
        cryptresult = cryptresult + String.fromCharCode(q.charCodeAt(0) ^ k.charCodeAt(0));
        i = i +1;
    }

    
    // write crypted string to file
    var outStreamW = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    outStreamW.Type = adTypeText;
    // Charset: the default value seems to be `UTF-16` (BOM `0xFFFE` for text files)
    outStreamW.Open();
    outStreamW.WriteText(cryptresult);
    outStreamW.Position = 0;

    var outStreamA = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    outStreamA.Type = adTypeText;
    outStreamA.Charset = "windows-1252"; // important, see `cdoCharset Module Constants`
    outStreamA.Open();

    outStreamW.CopyTo(outStreamA);      // convert encoding

    outStreamA.SaveToFile(fileOut, adSaveCreateOverWrite);

    outStreamW.Close();
    outStreamA.Close();
    
}
```

**EDIT:**
More troubleshooting into my code shows that when I encrypt and decrypt file.exe ON THE FLY,  and then write the decrypted data to fileenc.exe, fileenc.exe works well.

But when I encrypt file.exe and write the encrypted data to fileenc.txt and then read the fileenc.txt, decrypt the read encrypted data and write to fileenc.exe (just like in my code), fileenc.exe gets corrupted. My understanding suggests that the manner through which I write the encrypted data to fileenc.txt could be the problem here.

Please I need help, how do I go about with this.

Comment: How have you verified that file.exe and filedec.exe are the same ?

Comment: Shouldn't the write stream also be `windows-1252` to avoid extra unwanted characters during the `CopyTo()`?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen filedec.exe is expected to be the same with file.exe. I only encrypted file.exe and then decrypted it then save the decrypted copy as filedec.exe. They should be the same and work the same way, but it doesn't.

Comment: @user692942 Just tried that, not working. You can play with the code to see for yourself.

Comment: You state: "file.exe and filedec.exe are the same and are expected to function the same way." Have you actually verified that the files are the same ?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I expect fildec.exe to be the same with file.exe and function the same way after the encryption and decryption of file.exe which I wrote to a file as filedec.exe after decryption. However, they do not function the same way. Filedec.exe ends up somewhat corrupted by the encryption process and gives an error when execute while the original file.exe still executes fine.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen please see the new edit in the original question. Thank you.

Comment: @user692942 please see the new edit in the original question. Thank you.